# Should be able to access CallHistory.storedata on jailbroken phone? But unable to

Tags: ios, jailbreak, calllog

I can access the call log (call_history.db) on older OS version but I can't access it (CallHistory.storedata) on jailbroken 9.0.1.

This will return false:

```
NSString *callHisoryDatabasePath =  @"/private/var/mobile/Library/CallHistoryDB/CallHistory.storedata";    
BOOL callHistoryFileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:callHisoryDatabasePath];
```

And in fact I can't even  see the presence of var/mobile/... on the device, the following code reveals the presence of the var/mobile directory but not the var/mobile/Library directory or any other subdirectory of var/mobile

```
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath: @"/private/"];
    NSString *nextItem = [NSString string];
    while( (nextItem = [dirnum nextObject])) {
        {
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", nextItem);
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Why does the above code not list out the /var/mobile/Library/CallHistoryDB/ directory and contents?

Comment: Have you unlocked your test phone with passcode? it's available only when the phone is unlocked with passcode.